# Advice on methodology for changing datasource of angular material2 datatable

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, angular-material2

I have an Angular Material2 Database component that I designed that is populated based on a service which makes an http call to my Django database using the django rest framework.  I need to present several of these datatables in my website, each with different data using a different URL to the same backend datasource to get the data.  I am new to Angular and to the optimal architecture for the language in designing the site.  Do I:

1. Create a new component for each datatable, passing the url to the service?
2. Create a new component for each datatable and a new service for each url?
3. Create a single datatable component with a controller and have it connect to the same service, passing the url?  Should directives be used to modify the source of the datatable?

Thanks for the help on this.  I searched multiple places and can't find an example of the situation that I have.  Connecting one datatable to an external source is very straight forward in design but multiple tables is a mystery of how best to design this in a DRY and component fashion.

Comment: Have you only kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with everything in programming ... it depends. It's really hard to make a recommendation without knowing about your application and requirements.

Here are some general considerations:

If the only difference is the data source (no other UI changes or different functionality) then multiple components does not seem very DRY.

For example, if you have a single component that displays active customers and inactive customers, only the data source is different and multiple components may not make sense.

OTOH, if you have a component that displays customers and another that displays products, making them two different components makes sense.

In terms of services, I have been seeing companies build a "general purpose" data retrieval service that knows how to go get any data given a URL. Then single purpose services that know how to work with each type of data. The single purpose services each call the general purpose service.

But your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do like that :

1) Datatable is a component that you need to use in your views.

2) You want to use directive to provide data in your datatable component. You could pass options as well.

3) You need to create one service to manage a CRUD of your kind of data.

4) You could create a model to define your kind of data

Example : Showing a table of users

You use [md-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) component in your view.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]=”myDataArray”>
  ...
</mat-table>
```

You create a service UserService to get your array of user from a webservice :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  public getAll():Observable<User>{
     ...
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

You use your service in your component :

```
getUsers(): void {
  this.userService.getAll()
      .subscribe(users => this.myDataArray = users);
}


constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
```

You should replace User by your kind of data.